# Tried installing MongoDB with brew and it says "Error: Permission denied - (mongod.conf, /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf)"

Tags: macos, mongodb

Using Mac OSX 10.10.4 on  13' Macbook Air

Typed in 'brew update' like the Mongo docs said and it updated
Then typed 'brew install mongodb' and it took ages to say

```
Error: Permission denied - (mongod.conf, /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf)
```

This is what the console said leading up to that point, in case this helps:

```
Joshuas-Air:~ Josh$ brew install mongodb
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/mongodb-3.0.4.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring mongodb-3.0.4.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
==> Installing mongodb dependency: scons
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/scons-2.3.5.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring scons-2.3.5.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/scons/2.3.5: 208 files, 2.4M
==> Downloading https://fastdl.mongodb.org/src/mongodb-src-r3.0.4.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Cloning https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools.git
Updating /Library/Caches/Homebrew/mongodb--github.com-mongodb-mongo-tools--git
==> Checking out tag r3.0.4
==> ./build.sh
==> /usr/local/opt/scons/bin/scons install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.0.4 -j4 --osx-version-min=10.10 --cc=/usr/bin/clang --cxx=/usr/bin/clang++ --use-new-tools
Error: Permission denied - (mongod.conf, /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf)
Joshuas-Air:~ Josh$
```

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the permissions on the folder /usr/local/ are not set 755 or 777.
You can change the permissions or simply try to run the command as root:

```
sudo brew install mongodb
```

Comment: The response to using sudo is ```jsError: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew install`
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk.```

Comment: Try to change the permission on the folders. It is the recommended way: `sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/etc/` and '/usr/local/Cellar/`

Comment: i still get the error but the install now continues @Kikohs

Comment: forcing commands like this with sudo will almost always push the permission issue off to another operation later down the road. See Kris Wheeler's solution below (worked for me)

Answer (score 3):

I had mostly the same error. I could not solve the problem by chown'ing the /usr/local directories as the prompts suggest possibly due to my upgrade to High Sierra. I was able to succeed installing mongodb by reinstalling homebrew using the following command:

`$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

This allowed my subsequent `brew install mongodb` to work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, changing the directory permissions didn't work for me so eventually I've found this solution:

1. [Download](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads) the most recent version (`.tgz`).
2. Open the terminal and head to the `~/Downloads` folder or wherever you saved the file.
3. Untar: `tar xvf filename.tgz`.
4. Enter the directory and go to the `bin` directory.
5. At the terminal use the `sudo bash` (become root) command.
6. Now enter the command `cp * /usr/local/bin`.
7. Create `/data/db` directories (optional, this is the default location MongoDB uses).
8. At the terminal use the command `exit` to exit root user.
9. `which mongo` should now respond with `/usr/local/bin` and you are all set to go.